# Refresh Token and Access Token from Identity Server4

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, refresh-token

I tried to get the both access and refresh token by using below method but it returns invalid_scope and bad request. If I remove the offline_scope value for the scope it returns access token only.

```
 var tokenResponse = await protocolClient.RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync(new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest
                    {
                        Address = disco.TokenEndpoint,
                        ClientId = ServiceIdentity,
                        ClientSecret = ServiceKey,
                        Scope = "offline_access",
                        GrantType = "GrantTypes.ClientCredentials"
                    });
                    return tokenResponse.AccessToken;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's by design. `GrantTypes.ClientCredentials` does not support refresh token. The reason is that you can get a fresh access token anytime, using the same client id and secret.

Comment: so what should I do?

Comment: I sent GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPasswordAndClientCredentials also. But still  not works

Comment: just remove `offline_access`. get new access token by client creds when needed. for `ResourceOwnerPassword` `offline_access` must work, but... in most situations it's still excessive as you have locally all the creds to repeat the initial request

Comment: I got access token but I need refresh token also

Comment: once again: you say *I need*, but the answer is: *you don't*. why you guess you need refresh with client creds? could you explain your point?

Comment: I need to use refresh token to renew the access token once it get expired. So I want to get the refresh token along with access token.

Comment: am new to identityserver

Comment: well, the goal of refresh token is giving an application ability to renew access token **on behalf of a user** but without asking the user to re-enter their creds. service-like apps instead keep their creds inside and provide them each time they need a fresh access token. that's why refresh token is useful with `AuthorizationCode` or `Hybrid` flow (where a human involved), but in `ClientCredentials` flow (service-to service communication) that's not needed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195515/discussion-between-rajesh-and-d-f).